# Debug mode only exception in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

Is there a way in python to create an exception, or inherit from the `Exception` base class that will only raise if a global variable, like `debug_mode`, or something is set and if not it doesn't raise.

Comment: That really doesn't sound like it should be the exception's responsibility.

Comment: Given that ‘raise’ is a keyword(?) it is too late for an exception to do anything.